# Nodejs Express find by id and check other id exist in array or not

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I Need to find data by its and check that if in that Id there is no of arrays in which object Ids are saved need to match that also.

I try like this

```
const exists = await Partners.find({ '_id': req.params.id, partnerLikeuser: { $elemMatch: { $eq: req.user.partner_id } } },);
```

But its not working I need to find data by id in which partnerLikeuser array have `req.user.partner_id`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the best method but You can find like this. It will check `_id` and `partnerLikeuser` both.

```
const exists = await Partners.find({ '_id': req.params.id, partnerLikeuser: req.user.partner_id },);
```